# Can't make /path/to/file relative to /location/of/directory in Vercel serverless function

Tags: go, vercel

At the moment, I have an app that utilises Go serverless functions hosted with Vercel. When I try to execute some of them locally using 'vercel dev', I get the following error message:

```
Error! Command failed: /usr/local/lib/node_modules/vercel/node_modules/@vercel/go/dist/analyze -modpath=/Users/jon/Desktop/app api/fetch/fetchJobs.go
2022/12/03 16:32:30 Rel: can't make api/fetch/fetchDetails.go relative to /Users/jon/Desktop/app
```

However, they all execute absolutely fine on my production environment.

For reference, it's a React web app, so the directory structure is broadly as follows:

```
Root
  src 
     app components that call serverless functions
  api
     go functions
```

Does anyone have any suggestions for what's causing this?